# Fill in two MUI-Autocomplete fields based on one selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Trying to have a selection to set 2 different `Autocomplete` components on the same row in a table. Not sure if this is achievable and how to implement it based on the example below [feel free to check the sandbox for more context]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mendeleev-yhx7mp)

###### One can add a new row as shown below

[image]

###### Nonetheless, upon selection, only the `Fruit` column is filled in with the value, but not the corresponding value in `Calories`

[image]

###### In order to fill in `Calories` column, one has to select it manually

[image]

Now the gist is that each column is searchable based on its options and the requirement is to set the value of both columns based on the selection of one of the values in either column. When we select `Applesauce` for instance under `Fruit` column, I should expect `Calories` to get populated with `167`. Clearing a value also clears both in this case, and typing in to search for a value to be still working, since tried to have the `onChange` to set both values at once along with using `inputValue={}`, but that disabled the feature of typing in to search for a value. Is this attainable?

Thanks a tonne for the help in advance!

Here's the full code from the sandbox:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Box, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import AddBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddBox";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";

const columns = [
  {
    id: "name",
    label: "Fruit",
    minWidth: 100,
    align: "left",
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  },
  {
    id: "calories",
    label: "Calories",
    minWidth: 70,
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  }
];

function assignIds(data, newData = [], setNewData = undefined) {
  let id = 0;
  let newDataIds = [];
  data.forEach((entry) => {
    if (newData.includes(entry.id)) newDataIds.push(id);
    entry.id = id;
    id++;
  });
  if (setNewData) setNewData(newDataIds);
  return data;
}

const appDetails = {
  name: { name: "Fruit", style: { minWidth: 100, display: "flex" } },
  calories: { name: "Calories", style: { minWidth: 70, display: "flex" } }
};

const appDataRows = [
  { name: "Acai", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Apple", calories: "95" },
  { name: "Applesauce", calories: "167" },
  { name: "Apricot", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Avocado", calories: "320" },
  { name: "Banana", calories: "111" },
  { name: "Blackberries", calories: "62" },
  { name: "Blood", calories: "70" },
  { name: "Blueberries", calories: "84" },
  { name: "Cantaloupe", calories: "23" },
  { name: "Cherries", calories: "4" },
  { name: "Clementine", calories: "35" },
  { name: "Cranberries", calories: "46" },
  { name: "Currants", calories: "63" },
  { name: "Custard", calories: "136" },
  { name: "Dates", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Figs", calories: "37" },
  { name: "Fruit", calories: "125" },
  { name: "Grapes", calories: "104" },
  { name: "Greengage", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Guava", calories: "37" },
  { name: "Jackfruit", calories: "143" },
  { name: "Jujube", calories: "22" },
  { name: "Kiwi", calories: "112" },
  { name: "Lemon", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Lime", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Lychees", calories: "7" },
  { name: "Mandarin", calories: "47" },
  { name: "Mango", calories: "202" },
  { name: "Minneola", calories: "70" },
  { name: "Mulberries", calories: "60" },
  { name: "Nectarine", calories: "66" },
  { name: "Olives", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Orange", calories: "62" },
  { name: "Papaya", calories: "215" },
  { name: "Passion", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Peach", calories: "59" },
  { name: "Pear", calories: "101" },
  { name: "Persimmon", calories: "32" },
  { name: "Physalis", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Pineapple", calories: "453" },
  { name: "Plantains", calories: "218" },
  { name: "Plum", calories: "30" },
  { name: "Pomegranate", calories: "234" },
  { name: "Quince", calories: "52" },
  { name: "Raisins", calories: "434" },
  { name: "Rambutan", calories: "7" },
  { name: "Raspberries", calories: "64" },
  { name: "Rhubarb", calories: "11" },
  { name: "Starfruit", calories: "28" },
  { name: "Strawberries", calories: "49" },
  { name: "Tamarind", calories: "5" },
  { name: "Tangerine", calories: "47" },
  { name: "Watermelon", calories: "86" }
];

export default function AutocompleteTable() {
  const [rows] = useState(assignIds([]));
  const [modifiedRows, setModifiedRows] = useState([...rows]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);

  const handleAddFruit = () => {
    const newRowId =
      modifiedRows.length === 0
        ? -1
        : Math.max(...modifiedRows.map((mapping) => mapping.id));
    setPage(Math.floor((modifiedRows.length - rowsPerPage) / rowsPerPage + 1));
    setModifiedRows([
      ...modifiedRows,
      {
        id: newRowId + 1,
        name: "",
        calories: ""
      }
    ]);
  };

  const handleSearchInputChange = (event, key, id, input, reason) => {
    const list = [...modifiedRows];
    list[id][key.id] = reason === "clear" ? "" : input[key.field];
    setModifiedRows(list);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 430 }}>
        <Table
          stickyHeader
          aria-label="sticky table"
          style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}
        >
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{
                    minWidth: column.minWidth,
                    backgroundColor: "#e3e3e3"
                  }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}>
            {modifiedRows
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow
                    hover
                    role="checkbox"
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    key={row.id}
                    sx={{
                      "&:nth-of-type(odd)": { backgroundColor: "#ffffff" },
                      "&:nth-of-type(even)": { backgroundColor: "#faf5f5" }
                    }}
                  >
                    {columns.map((column) => {
                      return (
                        <TableCell
                          key={column.id}
                          align={column.align}
                          style={{
                            overflow: "hidden",
                            textOverflow: "ellipsis"
                          }}
                        >
                          <Autocomplete
                            autoHighlight
                            disableCloseOnSelect
                            key={column.id}
                            id={column.id}
                            options={appDataRows}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option[column.id]}
                            componentsProps={{
                              paper: { sx: { width: 230 } }
                            }}
                            onChange={(e, input, reason) =>
                              handleSearchInputChange(
                                e,
                                column,
                                row.id,
                                input,
                                reason
                              )
                            }
                            renderInput={(params) => {
                              return (
                                <TextField
                                  key={column.id}
                                  {...params}
                                  placeholder={column.label}
                                />
                              );
                            }}
                            renderOption={(props, option) => (
                              <table style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}>
                                {appDataRows.indexOf(option) === 0 && (
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr
                                      style={{
                                        paddingLeft: 15,
                                        display: "flex"
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      {Object.keys(option).map((key) => (
                                        <th
                                          style={{ ...appDetails[key].style }}
                                        >
                                          {appDetails[key].name}
                                        </th>
                                      ))}
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                )}
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr {...props} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                                    {Object.keys(option).map((key) => (
                                      <td style={{ ...appDetails[key].style }}>
                                        {option[key]}
                                      </td>
                                    ))}
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            )}
                          />
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Button onClick={handleAddFruit}>
          <AddBoxIcon />
          add
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to be aware of is that `Autocomplete` has both an `inputValue` prop and a `value` prop. `inputValue` can be provided to use a [controlled](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components) approach for the text being typed into the `Autocomplete`. `value` can be provided to use a controlled approach for the selected value for the `Autocomplete`. It sounds like you tried doing something with `inputValue`, but `value` is the prop that you want to work with in conjunction with `onChange` (`inputValue` works in conjunction with `onInputChange`).

The key changes I made were:

- Instead of each row having `id`, `name`, and `calories`, I changed it to just have `id` and `value` where `value` points at the selected option object (which has both `name` and `calories` properties within it). `value` is null when nothing is selected. This involved changes to the adding of a new row (`handleAddFruit`) and changes to `handleSearchInputChange` for when a value is selected or cleared.
- Use a [controlled](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components) approach for the `value` prop of the `Autocomplete` and pass `row.value` into it.

These two changes ensure that the selected value stays in sync for the pair of `Autocomplete` elements because they share the exact same state for the selected value.

The other changes I made were just to simplify some aspects of your code that were unnecessary at least in this example (I'm guessing they are remnants from how this component is meant to interact with it's parent component in a broader app).

Here's an updated version of your code and sandbox:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Box, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import AddBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddBox";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";

const columns = [
  {
    id: "name",
    label: "Fruit",
    minWidth: 100,
    align: "left",
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  },
  {
    id: "calories",
    label: "Calories",
    minWidth: 70,
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  }
];

const appDetails = {
  name: { name: "Fruit", style: { minWidth: 100, display: "flex" } },
  calories: { name: "Calories", style: { minWidth: 70, display: "flex" } }
};

const appDataRows = [
  { name: "Acai", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Apple", calories: "95" },
  { name: "Applesauce", calories: "167" },
  { name: "Apricot", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Avocado", calories: "320" },
  { name: "Banana", calories: "111" },
  { name: "Blackberries", calories: "62" },
  { name: "Blood", calories: "70" },
  { name: "Blueberries", calories: "84" },
  { name: "Cantaloupe", calories: "23" },
  { name: "Cherries", calories: "4" },
  { name: "Clementine", calories: "35" },
  { name: "Cranberries", calories: "46" },
  { name: "Currants", calories: "63" },
  { name: "Custard", calories: "136" },
  { name: "Dates", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Figs", calories: "37" },
  { name: "Fruit", calories: "125" },
  { name: "Grapes", calories: "104" },
  { name: "Greengage", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Guava", calories: "37" },
  { name: "Jackfruit", calories: "143" },
  { name: "Jujube", calories: "22" },
  { name: "Kiwi", calories: "112" },
  { name: "Lemon", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Lime", calories: "20" },
  { name: "Lychees", calories: "7" },
  { name: "Mandarin", calories: "47" },
  { name: "Mango", calories: "202" },
  { name: "Minneola", calories: "70" },
  { name: "Mulberries", calories: "60" },
  { name: "Nectarine", calories: "66" },
  { name: "Olives", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Orange", calories: "62" },
  { name: "Papaya", calories: "215" },
  { name: "Passion", calories: "17" },
  { name: "Peach", calories: "59" },
  { name: "Pear", calories: "101" },
  { name: "Persimmon", calories: "32" },
  { name: "Physalis", calories: "2" },
  { name: "Pineapple", calories: "453" },
  { name: "Plantains", calories: "218" },
  { name: "Plum", calories: "30" },
  { name: "Pomegranate", calories: "234" },
  { name: "Quince", calories: "52" },
  { name: "Raisins", calories: "434" },
  { name: "Rambutan", calories: "7" },
  { name: "Raspberries", calories: "64" },
  { name: "Rhubarb", calories: "11" },
  { name: "Starfruit", calories: "28" },
  { name: "Strawberries", calories: "49" },
  { name: "Tamarind", calories: "5" },
  { name: "Tangerine", calories: "47" },
  { name: "Watermelon", calories: "86" }
];

export default function AutocompleteTable() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);

  const handleAddFruit = () => {
    setPage(Math.floor((rows.length - rowsPerPage) / rowsPerPage + 1));
    setRows([
      ...rows,
      {
        id: rows.length,
        value: null
      }
    ]);
  };

  const handleSearchInputChange = (event, id, input, reason) => {
    const list = [...rows];
    list[id].value = reason === "clear" ? null : input;
    setRows(list);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 430 }}>
        <Table
          stickyHeader
          aria-label="sticky table"
          style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}
        >
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{
                    minWidth: column.minWidth,
                    backgroundColor: "#e3e3e3"
                  }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}>
            {rows
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow
                    hover
                    role="checkbox"
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    key={row.id}
                    sx={{
                      "&:nth-of-type(odd)": { backgroundColor: "#ffffff" },
                      "&:nth-of-type(even)": { backgroundColor: "#faf5f5" }
                    }}
                  >
                    {columns.map((column) => {
                      return (
                        <TableCell
                          key={column.id}
                          align={column.align}
                          style={{
                            overflow: "hidden",
                            textOverflow: "ellipsis"
                          }}
                        >
                          <Autocomplete
                            autoHighlight
                            disableCloseOnSelect
                            key={column.id}
                            id={column.id}
                            options={appDataRows}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option[column.id]}
                            componentsProps={{
                              paper: { sx: { width: 230 } }
                            }}
                            value={row.value}
                            onChange={(e, input, reason) =>
                              handleSearchInputChange(e, row.id, input, reason)
                            }
                            renderInput={(params) => {
                              return (
                                <TextField
                                  key={column.id}
                                  {...params}
                                  placeholder={column.label}
                                />
                              );
                            }}
                            renderOption={(props, option) => (
                              <table style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}>
                                {appDataRows.indexOf(option) === 0 && (
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr
                                      style={{
                                        paddingLeft: 15,
                                        display: "flex"
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      {Object.keys(option).map((key) => (
                                        <th
                                          style={{ ...appDetails[key].style }}
                                        >
                                          {appDetails[key].name}
                                        </th>
                                      ))}
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                )}
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr {...props} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                                    {Object.keys(option).map((key) => (
                                      <td style={{ ...appDetails[key].style }}>
                                        {option[key]}
                                      </td>
                                    ))}
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            )}
                          />
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Button onClick={handleAddFruit}>
          <AddBoxIcon />
          add
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete pair]